# Dasa Paramitha - Sources

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, paramitas

Where can I find sutras describing about the 10 paramithas and the 3 types of paramithas in the pali cannon? I couldn't find a proper sutra on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a study guide here by Thanissaro Bhikkhu: [The Ten Perfections
A Study Guide](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/perfections.html)

There seem to be four types of perfection, and not three.

> Passages in this guide are drawn from the Pali canon and from the teachings of Ajaan Lee Dhammadharo.
>
> > The four determinations:
> > One should not be negligent of *discernment*,
> > should guard the *truth*,
> > be devoted to *relinquishment*,
> > and train only for *calm*.
>
> — [MN 140](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.140.than.html)

You can find a further commentary here by Bhikkhu Bodhi: [A Treatise on the Paramis
From the Commentary to the Cariyapitaka](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/wheel409.html)